# Tutorial for Google Maps API

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api, api, references, google

Where I can find some good tutorial for Google Maps API?

Comment: What tutorials have you looked at so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used these to get started - then google when I got stuck.

- http://www.w3schools.com/graphics/google_maps_intro.asp
- https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial

Answer (score 1):

This is a good source to get started [here](http://chrisholtz.com/blog/getting-started-with-the-google-maps-api/)

The author give a step-by-step process and helps you get your first embedded map setup using the Google Maps API.